# Android Bottom Navigation View Customisation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am new to Android development. I am trying to have a bottom navigation view similar to below attached image

[image]

With a background color of selected menu and also a middle button to be overflow over nav bar. Few key points to note in this is:

- there is no title with icons List item.
- The middle icon is overflown from navigation bar.
- The background color is changing on selection of the tab instead of icon color.

If any tutorial or any guidance available then let me know.

Thank you (in advance)

Comment: For Customized Bottom Navigation you can get the code from Here :: https://www.androidtutorialonline.com/curved-bottom-navigation-view/

Comment: HI,
Were yo uable to find the solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [SpaceNavigationView](https://github.com/armcha/Space-Navigation-View) library to get the Bottom Navigation Bar similar to your required design. The library has the option for an overflow icon in the center and also there is no title with icons. However, I am not sure if the is any background color change feature on selection of tab in the library. You can also take a look at other libraries and see if the source codes can be of any help.

- https://github.com/armcha/Space-Navigation-View
- https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation
- https://github.com/sephiroth74/Material-BottomNavigation
- https://github.com/Ashok-Varma/BottomNavigation

Comment: I tried the SpaceNavigationView but it didn't workout for me. So now I am trying `BottomNavigationViewEx` but this also seems to be lacking the overflow thing.

Comment: The SpaceNavigationView has the overflow icon. Doesn't it meet your requirements?

Comment: It have a curve on top of it. So its not helping.

Comment: After looking into the code, it seems that the creator of SpaceNavigationView has added the centre_part_linear attribute to disable bezier curve at centre. Take a look into the [sample XML](https://github.com/armcha/Space-Navigation-View/blob/master/Sample/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml) and see if it works.

Comment: space navigation view shows unable to marge dex

Answer (score 1):

I can answer about guidance.

1. Check [**BottomNavigationView**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) documentation. Play with [OnTabSelectListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.html) to change background color on selection. Play with dynamic items adding, to make your central item overflown.
2. Before `BottomNavigationView` was added to Android SDK, some kind peron wrote **[BottomBar](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar)** library. This library implements even more, then `BottomNavigationView`, including background color change. Its source code might be helpful for you.

Comment: Hello, thank you for such a kind help. It will be really helpful for me. :) but will there be any guidance for overflow icon in middle?

Answer (score 0):

Fully customization lib https://github.com/AndroidHelp/bottomnavigation

Change Font of tab item
Add Badge in tab etc

Comment: Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure with your [answer link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259)
 While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.
 [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Sure I will elaborate for next time.